# Cross and checked Pattern apply for Selected area in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

I am new to graphics field I would like apply cross and checked pattern with in selected image area in Photoshop and I don't have any ready cross and checked patterns.

Anyone can share the procedure to create and apply cross and checked pattern in image using photoshop cs5

Answer (score 4):

Make your own.

1. Open up a new document and set some suitable pixel dimensions like 40 x 40.
2. Select **<kbd>Edit → Preferences → Guides, Grid and Slices...</kbd>** and set your grid spacing to 10 pixel intervals, or something suitable to your size.
3. Make sure grid snap is turned on, in **<kbd>View → Snap → Grid</kbd>**.
4. With rectangular marquee select, one lower quadrant, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> down and select opposite quadrant.
5. Fill with foreground color.  <kbd>Alt/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (backspace).

   [image: Steps 4 and 5]

   **Image 1**: Select with marque, shift select and fill.
6. Select everything. <kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
7. Choose **<kbd>Edit → Define PAttern...</kbd>**,
8. Done with Checker, adapt  these instructions for grid (should be straightforward).

### To use

1. In the layer bar choose the adjustment layer button and choose **Pattern**

   [image: Pattern adjustment]

   **Image 2**: Chosing pattern layer
2. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @joojaa, it is the way to do it. I would just recommend to save your pattern so that you can have it in future. the way to do it if you need to:

double click on the empty area

[image]

select pattern overlay

[image]

select your check pattern you created earlier!

[image]

Save your pattern

[image]